# how to create a List type of non public class from another package?

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, collections

My Package A has one java file with 2 classes. Login class which is public and LoginDetails class which cannot be public because it is in the same file. how to create a List of LoginDetails type from Package B.

```
package A;


public class Login {

    
    private String name;
    private String passWord;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Login [name=" + name + ", passWord=" + passWord + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
class LoginDetails{
    
    public LoginDetails(int id, int geight) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.geight = geight;
    }
    private int id;
    private int geight;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getGeight() {
        return geight;
    }
    public void setGeight(int geight) {
        this.geight = geight;
    }
    public void hidden() {
        System.out.println("From hidden");
    }
    public LoginDetails() {
        
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
package B;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        List<LoginDetails> l = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you separate the class into its own file? Or use `Login.LoginDetails` if you for some reason cannot.

Comment: You cannot directly create a list of `LoginDetails` in a class outside package `A`, since class `LoginDetails` is not visible outside the package. Why not move class `LoginDetails` to its own source file and make it public?

Comment: @Jesper thanks for your reply. I am able to achieve it if I write LoginDetails in a separate source file. But, my requirement is not to change the code and still would be able to access LoginDetails class.

Comment: That's going to be difficult then, because your requirements are not possible...

Comment: Is this homework? Any way I could imagine doing this under your constraints would involve bad program design.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your weird question which doesnt include changing neither of the `Login` nor `LoginDetails` classes would be by adding a second Public class called `AUtils` such like this:

**AUtils/AFactory class**

```
package A;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AUtils  {
    public static ArrayList<LoginDetails> generateList(){
        return new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    }
    public static ArrayList<LoginDetails> generateListWithInitialSize(int x){
        return new ArrayList<LoginDetails>(x);
    }

    public static LoginDetails generateAnObject(){
        return new LoginDetails();
    }

    public static LoginDetails generateWithData(int id, int geight){
       return new LoginDetails(id,geight);
    }
}
```

And your **`Demo`** would look like this:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {//plus you dont need To throw exception thus your program dont throw any!:)

        List l = AUtils.generateList();
//        List l = AUtils.generateListWithInitialSize(10);//will give you array list with initial size 10

        l.add(AUtils.generateAnObject());//if you do so be aware that the objects would be created with 0 as id and eight.
//        l.add(AUtils.generateWithData(3,3));
    }

}
```

please be aware that this normally is not acceptable and considered as bad coding because its kinda turn around ;) so either you misunderstood the assignment or the one who wrote it is really a carrot.

happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly without changing of the design or visibility of the classes.

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as
> package-private), it is visible only within its own package.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html